# Deduce orthogonality relations for sine and cosine using $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{inx}e^{-imx}dx$ is 0 if $m\neq n$ and $2\pi$ if $m=n$.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers

The following is problem 7 of chapter 9.10 in Apostol's *Calculus*, Volume I.

> If $m$ and $n$ are integers prove that
>
> $$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{inx}e^{-imx}dx=\begin{cases}0\ \ \ \ \ \text{if}\
>  m\neq n\\ 2\pi\ \ \ \ \text{if}\ m=n\end{cases}$$
>
> Use part (a) to deduce the orthogonality relations for the sine and
> cosine ($m$ and $n$ are integers, $m^2\neq n^2$):
>
> $$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin{nx}\cos{mx}dx=\int_0^{2\pi}
>  \sin{nx}\sin{mx}dx=\int_0^{2\pi} \cos{nx}\cos{mx}dx$$
>
> $$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2{nx}dx=\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2{nx}dx=\pi$$

To solve part (a), we write $e^{inx}e^{-imx}=e^{ix(n-m)}$.

If $m=n$ then this expression is 1, and so the integral of 1 from 0 to $2\pi$ is $2\pi$.

If $m\neq n$ then we use Euler's formula and integrate. The result is zero.

My question is how do we solve part (b) using part (a)?

I can solve part (b) by using the trigonometric identities for $\sin{(a\pm b)}$ and $\cos{(a\pm b)}$ with $a=mx$ and $b=nx$.

Comment: I may be missing something, but what is wrong with using the fact that
$$ e^{inx}e^{-imx} = [\cos(nx) + i\sin(nx)][\cos(mx) - i\sin(mx)] $$
To get the relations you're looking for?

Comment: Suppose we integrate both sides when $m\neq n$. The left side is 0. Thus, $0=\int (\cos{nx}\cos{mx}+\sin{nx}\sin{mx} +i(-\cos{nx}\sin{mx}+\sin{nx}\cos{mx}))dx$. We equate the integrals in each of the  real and imaginary parts to zero. But each of these terms is a sum of two integrals. I am not sure how to proceed after this to show that the individual integrals are zero.

Comment: Replace $m \to -m$ and repeat your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Using (a) to prove (b), we may use the identity $e^{iy}=\cos y+i\sin y$.

For $m^2\ne n^2$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin n x \cos m x d x = & \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{i n x}-e^{-i n x}}{2 i} \cdot \frac{e^{i m x}+e^{-i m x}}{2} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{4i} \int_0^{2 \pi}\left(e^{i(m+n) x}-e^{i m x} \cdot e^{-i n x}+e^{i n x} e^{-i m x}+e^{-i(m+n)x}\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{4i} \int_0^{2 \pi} 2 \cos (m+n) x d x \\
= & 0
\end{aligned}
$$
Similarly for the remaining two.

When $m=n$, $$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^2 n x  d x = & \int_0^{2 \pi} \left( \frac{e^{i n x}-e^{-i n x}}{2 i}\right)^2 dx\\
= & -\frac{1}{4 } \int_0^{2 \pi}\left(e^{2ni x}-e^{i nx} \cdot e^{-i n x}-e^{i n x} e^{-i nx}+e^{-2nix}\right) dx\\
= & -\frac{1}{4}\left(\int_0^{2 \pi} 2 \cos 2n x d x-2 \pi-2 \pi\right) \\
= & \pi
\end{aligned}
$$
Similarly for cosine.